# "Overload" F9 (or shift+F9) in Excel spreadsheet with VBA function?

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way I can get a VBA module to be called when <kbd>F9</kbd> is pressed? I would like to execute Application.Volatile when the user presses <kbd>F9</kbd>?

Comment: @mehow Seriously? VBA questions should go to superuser?

Answer (score 2):

According to MSDN `Application.Volatile` :

> Marks a user-defined function as volatile. A volatile function must be
>   recalculated whenever calculation occurs in any cells on the
>   worksheet. A nonvolatile function is recalculated only when the input
>   variables change. This method has no effect if it's not inside a
>   user-defined function used to calculate a worksheet cell.

This (and other) mean that:

1. instruction works only with functions, not Module
2. it will work with all User Defined functions also as a result of pressing <kbd>F9</kbd>
3. it's required to place the instruction at the beginning of UDF.

See example of UDF with `Application.Volatile`:

```
Function ReturnCurrentTimer()
    Application.Volatile
    ReturnCurrentTimer = Timer
End Function
```